# Ambiguous reference from a Fortran module

Tags: compilation, fortran, precision

I am writing a code for an aproximate integral calculator using the Simpson's, trapezoid and Gauss rule in Fortran. The assignment requires to use a module to assign precision, but when I try to compile my code I get the following error message:

```
Name ‘pr’ at (1) is an ambiguous reference to ‘pr’ from module ‘precs’
```

I'm not sure if it is a compilation mistake or something is wrong with the code.

The compilation command i am using is:

```
gfortran P3.f90 intmod.f90 gaussmod.f90 precision.f90 -o P3.exe
```

I don't get error messages when compiling the other modules.

On the other hand, the code I am using is:

```
    program P3

    use gaussmod
    use integral
    use precs

    implicit none

    real(pr)                            :: aa, bb, s, ie, ss, st

    integer                             :: i, j, k, h, t, p

    real(pr), dimension(:), allocatable :: xx, ww
```

And my precision module is:

```
    module precs

implicit none

integer, parameter :: sp = kind(1.0)
integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
integer, parameter :: tp = selected_real_kind(p=precision(1._dp)+1)
integer, parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind(p=precision(1._tp)+1)

integer, parameter :: pr = qp

end module precs
```

Comment: Are there other entities called `pr` in other modules?

Comment: No, but I used the same precision module for the other two modules.

Comment: can you list the declaration part of the other modules (specially the public parameter and variables declaration)?

Comment: There is insufficient information.  Try making everything in your modules private, exporting only public entities, and then import only the entities that you need from a module.

Comment: Note that the actual precisions of kinds `sp`, `dp`, `tp` and `qp` will depend on the processor.  According to your definitions: reals of kind `sp` simply have default precision, they need not be 32-bit variables, less be IEEE 754 32-bit base-2 floating-point variables.  Reals of kind `dp` will have double precision, but the requirements on them are quite loose (decimal precision ≥10, more than the real default, and exponent range ≥37, see paragraphs 5-6 of section 4.4.2.3. of the 2008 standard), they need not be IEEE 754 64-bit base-2 floating point variables, or even 64-bit.

Comment: (cont.) A processor doesn't have to support more than two representations of floating point variables, if that's the case `tp` will be negative (see paragraph 7 of section 13.7.147 on `selected_real_kind`), the definition of `qp` using `1._tp` will be invalid (kinds cannot be negative), and compilation will fail.  If two additional representations (kinds) are supported, and their precisions are not only different than the default and double (you can have multiple kinds with the same precision), but also bigger than the double, your module will compile, but who knows what they will be...

Comment: If you want to ensure that you are using 32-, 64- or 128-bit floating point variables, you should use the `real32`, `real64` and `real128` kinds provided by the `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` intrinsic module.  If you want to ensure that you are using IEEE 754 base-2 floating point variables, you should obtain your kinds from appropriate calls to the `IEEE_SELECTED_REAL_KIND` function provided by the `IEEE_ARITHMETIC` intrinsic module.  If any of the kinds returned is negative: bad luck, that representation is not supported by your processor.